# Future<String?> always return null

Tags: flutter, api, dart, dart-null-safety

sorry to bother you, but I have a problem that’s driving me crazy and I could use some help.
I’m creating an App and I have to work with APIs, in practice the API (which I’m sure works because the use on my website) must send me an image. To do this I wrote this function :

```
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:developer';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class ApiService{

 static Future<String?> callDalleService({required String promptText}) async {
 var queryStartTime = DateTime.now();

 final uri= Uri.parse('https://surfaces-notebook-biographies-paying.trycloudflare.com/dalle');
 final headers = {'Bypass-Tunnel-Reminder': "go"};
 Map<String, dynamic> body = {'text' : promptText,'num_images' : 1};
 String jsonBody = json.encode(body);
 final encoding = Encoding.getByName('utf-8');
 String? finalImage;

 final response = await http.post(
 uri,
 headers: headers,
 body: jsonBody,
 encoding: encoding,
 ).then((res) {
if(res.statusCode == 200) {
 var jsonResponse = jsonDecode(res.body);
 print(jsonResponse);
 return finalImage = jsonDecode(res.body)['generatedImgs'].toString();
}
 else
 {
 print('An Error occured with the response');
 return null;
 }
 });
 }
}
```

Then pass the parameter to another page like this :

```
onTap: () async{
 final promptText = _inputTextController.text;
 print('API call to DALL-E web service with the following prompt $promptText');
 setIsFetchingImgs == true;
 String? finalImage = await ApiService.callDalleService(promptText: _inputTextController.text);
 print(finalImage);
 if (finalImage != null) {
 Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>  new firstOutputPage(finalImage: finalImage),));
 }else{
 print('finalImage returned null');
 }
},
```

Only for some reason the string is always empty. I tried to spell out the value of the string this way :

```
return finalImage = "Test value";
```

But still it always comes back null... Please help me

Comment: Can you try checking `jsonDecode(res.body)['generatedImgs'].toString()` by print or debug

Comment: What does the console say? Does it print 'An Error occured with the response' or the jsonResponse? My guess is you don't get status 200 from the api and it always goes in the else case (return null)

Comment: `jsonDecode(res.body)['generatedImgs']` is a `List` so you likely need to index into it, perhaps as simply as adding `[0]` for the first member

Comment: I tried printare both res.statusCode(which returns 200) and jsonDecode(res.body)['generatedImgs']. tostring() (which returns a long string that starts with  [/9j/4AAAQSkZJRgABAAAAABAD/2wBDAgGgcGBQgHBwcJCCQgKDBQNDDAsLDDDkBSEw8UHRofH0aHwgC4C4nIsIsIxKDcpDDAxHyc5HDQ0PTPC4DDL).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't bother with `then` in an `async` function - just use `await`.

This snippet works as expected:

```
static Future<String?> callDalleService({required String promptText}) async {
  final response = await http.post(
    Uri.parse(
      'https://surfaces-notebook-biographies-paying.trycloudflare.com/dalle',
    ),
    headers: {'bypass-tunnel-reminder': 'go'},
    body: json.encode({'text': promptText, 'num_images': 1}),
  );

  if (response.statusCode != 200) {
    return null;
  }

  return json.decode(response.body)['generatedImgs'][0];
}
```

Comment: The value also print with my method, so that's not the problem.

Comment: edited so you can just copy/paste

Comment: Thank you so much now it works, but now how can I show the received image?

Comment: Decode the base 64 and put it in an `Image.memory` widget? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7oIAs-0G4mw